# .NET Remove/Strip JavaScript and CSS code blocks from HTML page

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I have HTML string with the JavaScript and CSS code blocks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  alert('hello world');

</script>

<style type="text/css">
  A:link {text-decoration: none}
  A:visited {text-decoration: none}
  A:active {text-decoration: none}
  A:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
</style>
```

How to strip those blocks? 
Any suggestion about the regular expressions that can be used to remove those?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The quick 'n' dirty method would be a regex like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(
   "(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)", 
   RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

string ouput = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

The better* (but possibly slower) option would be to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlInput);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script|//style");

foreach (var node in nodes)
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

string htmlOutput = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

*) For a discussion about why it's better, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Do you know [Tony The Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: @GvS: I know about the problems that can arise when you are using regular expressions to process HTML. So for most cases I would strongly recommend an html parser like HtmlAgilityPack, but it depends on the situation. If it is a one-time batch to remove scripts and style blocks, and I know that the input is valid html, then my regex above can be sufficient, especially since `<script>` tags and `<style>` tags can't have nested tags.

Comment: @GvS: I added an example that uses HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Be careful of inline scripts also? E.g. <body onload ="doSomething()">?  Need to have a far more sophisticated tools to get rid of that.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTMLAgilityPack for better results

or try this function

```
public string RemoveScriptAndStyle(string HTML)
{
    string Pat = "<(script|style)\\b[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>";
    return Regex.Replace(HTML, Pat, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look for an opening `<script` tag, and then remove everything between it and the closing `/script>` tag.

Likewise for the style.  [See Google](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=c#%20string%20manipulation&aq=0&aqi=g3g-c1g1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=e7857f8e6e239bef&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e7857f8e6e239bef&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=1085) for string manipulation tips.

Comment: doesn't work if your code has document.write("</script>") in it

Comment: is it sufficient to just do this in security sense? (prevent javascript from executing)?

Answer (score 1):

I made my bike) He may not be as correct as HtmlAgilityPack but it is much faster by about 5-6 times on a page in the 400 kb. Also make symbols lowercase and remove digits(made for tokenizer)

```
 private static readonly List<byte[]> SPECIAL_TAGS = new List<byte[]>
                                                            {
                                                                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("script"),
                                                                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("style"),
                                                                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("noscript")
                                                            };

    private static readonly List<byte[]> SPECIAL_TAGS_CLOSE = new List<byte[]>
                                                                  {
                                                                      Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("/script"),
                                                                      Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("/style"),
                                                                      Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("/noscript")};

public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source, bool toLowerCase)
    {
        var array = new char[source.Length];
        var arrayIndex = 0;
        var inside = false;
        var haveSpecialTags = false;
        var compareIndex = -1;
        var singleQouteMode = false;
        var doubleQouteMode = false;
        var matchMemory = SetDefaultMemory(SPECIAL_TAGS);
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            var let = source[i];
            if (inside && !singleQouteMode && !doubleQouteMode)
            {
                compareIndex++;
                if (haveSpecialTags)
                {
                    var endTag = CheckSpecialTags(let, compareIndex, SPECIAL_TAGS_CLOSE, ref matchMemory);
                    if (endTag) haveSpecialTags = false;
                }
                if (!haveSpecialTags)
                {
                    haveSpecialTags = CheckSpecialTags(let, compareIndex, SPECIAL_TAGS, ref matchMemory);
                }
            }
            if (haveSpecialTags && let == '"')
            {
                doubleQouteMode = !doubleQouteMode;
            }
            if (haveSpecialTags && let == '\'')
            {
                singleQouteMode = !singleQouteMode;
            }
            if (let == '<')
            {
                matchMemory = SetDefaultMemory(SPECIAL_TAGS);
                compareIndex = -1;
                inside = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (let == '>')
            {
                inside = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (inside) continue;
            if (char.IsDigit(let)) continue; 
            if (haveSpecialTags) continue;
            array[arrayIndex] = toLowerCase ? Char.ToLowerInvariant(let) : let;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }

    private static bool[] SetDefaultMemory(List<byte[]> specialTags)
    {
        var memory = new bool[specialTags.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
        {
            memory[i] = true;
        }
        return memory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Elian Ebbing's answer and Rajeev's answer, I opted for the more stable solution of using an HTML library, not regular expressions. But instead of using HtmlAgilityPack I used [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io), which gave me jquery-like selectors, in .NET Core 3:

```
//using AngleSharp;
var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(sourceHtml)); // generate HTML DOM from source html string
var elems = document.QuerySelectorAll("script, style"); // get script and style elements
foreach(var elem in elems)
{
    var parent = elem.Parent;
    parent.RemoveChild(elem); // remove element from DOM
}
var resultHtml = document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml; // HTML result as a string
```