# Disable active content in WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf

I have embedded a WebBrowser control in my application and display content that I receive from a server. Specifically: The control is bound to a string which contains the error message from a rest call, that sometimes is HTML.

I wonder if there is a security risk if active content, e.g. JavaScript would be sent as part of the error message. Is there a way to instruct the WebBrowser control to disable all active content?

Comment: Could you please explain more clear? If you want to disable javascript code/html from server you can easily to do. If you trust the server, it even more easier to deal with what server send to you.

Comment: Quite the opposite. I do not trust the server. I want to display the content in a WebBrowser view but have all active content deactivated.

Comment: Does that mean you want to disable WebBrowser javascript completely?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable any active content. The whole purpose is to display information that happens to be formatted as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do:

First way is remove javascript from your string before pass it to browser, from [Elian Ebbing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6383757/1560697):

> The quick 'n' dirty method would be a regex like this:
>
> ```
> var regex = new Regex(
>    "(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)", 
>    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
> );
>
> string ouput = regex.Replace(input, "");
> ```
>
> The better* (but possibly slower) option would be to use
>   [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):
>
> ```
> HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();    doc.LoadHtml(htmlInput);
> var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script|//style");
> foreach (var node in nodes)       node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
> string htmlOutput = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
> ```
>
> *) For a discussion about why it's better, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

That way seem better and easier.

Second way is use WinForms webbrowser control, which allow you control lower level of browser, but this involve some invoking to WinAPI.

You can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445832/1560697) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Sakura. I may need to follow that approach. My thinking was however to instruct the WebBrowser control to disable active content like I can tell it my browser.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best if we can do. But [some people](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623739/1560697) say it is impossible.

Comment: @JohannesSchacht Thank :)